# Autocomplete inside a GridView

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

I can't seem to get this to work.  I'm sure this will be a series of questions (unless someone can show me some working example), but to start off...

I'm getting an error stating:

```
The name 'txtNewSongName' does not exist in the current context
```

Here's the relevant pieces of my asp.net code:
    
        $(function () {
            NewEmptyTrackName();

```
    });

    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    if (prm != null) {
        prm.add_endRequest(function (sender, e) {
            if (sender._postBackSettings.panelsToUpdate != null) {
                NewEmptyTrackName();

            }
        });
    };

    function NewEmptyTrackName() {

        $("#<%=txtNewSongName.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {

                    $.ajax({
                        url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/AutocompleteSetlist.asmx/SongCompletionList") %>',
                        data: "{ 'cSong': '" + request.term + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.split('|')[0],
                                    val: item.split('|')[1]
                                }
                            }))
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        },
                        failure: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                },
                select: function (e, i) {
                    $("#<%=hfNewSongName.ClientID %>").val(i.item.val);
            },
            minLength: 1
            });
        };
</script>

<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="ShowDiv3" Visible="false" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="0"  Width="1389px">
    <asp:Label ID="lblShowSetlist" runat="server" Text="Setlist:" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <%-- This line needed to be commented out when paging was removed: AllowPaging="True"  AllowCustomPaging="True" PageSize="10" --%>
    <div id="divGrid3" style='width:800px; overflow:auto'>
        <asp:GridView ID="DataGrid_Setlist" runat="server" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
            AllowSorting="True" OnSorting="DataGrid_Setlist_Sorting" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter ="true" CellPadding="1" 
            CssClass="hoverTable"
            HeaderStyle-BackColor="#4DA6A6" HeaderStyle-BorderColor="#4DA6A6" 
            HeaderStyle-Font-Size="Small" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
            FooterStyle-BackColor="#4DA6A6" FooterStyle-BorderColor="#4DA6A6" FooterStyle-ForeColor="White"
            DataKeyNames="DateID"
            OnDataBound="DataGrid_Setlist_OnDataBound"
            OnRowDataBound="DataGrid_Setlist_RowDataBound"
            OnRowCancelingEdit="DataGrid_Setlist_CancelCommand"   
            OnRowEditing="DataGrid_Setlist_EditCommand" 
            OnRowDeleting="DataGrid_Setlist_DeleteCommand"
            OnRowUpdating="DataGrid_Setlist_UpdateCommand">  

                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Song Order">  
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewSongOrder" runat="server" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </ItemTemplate>  
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Song Name">  
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewSongName" runat="server" Width="370px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </ItemTemplate>  
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Song Name">  
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hfNewSongName" runat="server"></asp:HiddenField>
                            </ItemTemplate>  
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="btn_Add" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="DataGrid_Setlist_RowCreated" />
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </columns>  
                </EmptyDataTemplate>

                <Columns>  

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Song Order">  
                        <ItemTemplate>  
                            <asp:Label ID="lblSongOrder" runat="server" Width="100px" Text='<%#Eval("SongOrder") %>'></asp:Label>  
                        </ItemTemplate>  
                        <EditItemTemplate>  
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewSongOrder" runat="server" Width="100px" Text='<%#Eval("SongOrder") %>'></asp:TextBox>  
                        </EditItemTemplate>  
                        <FooterTemplate>  
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewSongOrder" runat="server" Width="100px" ></asp:TextBox>  
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>                 

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Song Name">  
                        <ItemTemplate>  
                            <asp:Label ID="lblSongID" runat="server" Width="370px" Text='<%#Eval("SongID") %>'></asp:Label>  
                        </ItemTemplate>  
                        <EditItemTemplate>  
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewSongName" runat="server" Width="370px" Text='<%#Eval("SongID") %>'></asp:TextBox>  
                        </EditItemTemplate>  
                        <FooterTemplate>  
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewSongName" runat="server" Width="370px" ></asp:TextBox>  
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>   

                    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="90px">  
                    <ItemTemplate>  
                            <asp:Button ID="btn_Edit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit" />  
                    </ItemTemplate>  
                    <EditItemTemplate>  
                            <asp:Button ID="btn_Update" runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="Update"/>  
                            <asp:Button ID="btn_Cancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel"/>  
                    </EditItemTemplate>  
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="btn_Add" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="DataGrid_Setlist_RowCreated" />
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>  
                    <asp:TemplateField>  
                    <ItemTemplate>  
                            <asp:Button ID="btn_Delete" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('Are you sure?');" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" />  
                    </ItemTemplate>  
                    </asp:TemplateField>        

                </Columns>  
        </asp:GridView>  
        <asp:Label ID="lblEmpty1" runat="server" Visible="false" Style="font-weight:bold; font-size:large;"></asp:Label>
    </div> 
</asp:Panel>
```

What I'm trying to do is input songs in a specific order.  The song titles are being filled using an autocomplete web service.  I've utilized the web service on a few other pages so I'm sure that's OK, but I'm bad at Javascript and can't figure out why, when the textbox is inside a GridView, the code doesn't work.

Comment: it's been a long time since I worked in asp.net, but I do recall that the names you see in the aspx file aren't the same ones that the browser renders. I suspect that the field that you're reading data from or delivering data to gets its name changed in a way that breaks the javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that `<%=txtNewSongName.ClientID %>` does not work is because `txtNewSongName` only exists within a single GridView row. So from outside the GridView it is not accessibly because there could be more than one.

The most easy fix is to assign `autocomplete` to each TextBox within the GridView.
Start bij giving the TextBox a unique class to identify them

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNewSongName" runat="server" CssClass="AutoCompleteMe"></asp:TextBox>
```

Then you can use the jQuery `each` to bind the autocomplete function to it. See the snippet below. It wil change the text of each TextBox when focus is lost.

```
function NewEmptyTrackName() {
    $('#<%=DataGrid_Setlist.ClientID %> .AutoCompleteMe').each(function () {

        $(this).blur(function () {
            $(this).val("Testing...");
        });

    });
};
```

In your case it would become something like this

```
function NewEmptyTrackName() {
    $('#<%=DataGrid_Setlist.ClientID %> .AutoCompleteMe').each(function () {
        $(this).autocomplete({
        ...
```

If you absolutely need the ClientID from a TextBox witing the GridView, you have to access it by Index.

```
<%= ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("txtNewSongName")).ClientID %>
```

Comment: Autocomplete works great.  However, I need the SongID and not the Songname when I write the data to the table, and I put that last line of code you wrote into my code where I have $("#<%=hfNewSongName.ClientID %>").val(i.item.val); and it gave me an error saying "The name 'i' doesn't exist in the current context".  Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: @JohnnyBones sorry I do not really understand your comment. But if you need to find another element within the same row, use `closest`: `$(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=hidden]').val('Song ID');`

Comment: I needed to get the SongID passed back by the web service, so I just replaced 'Song ID' with i.item.val and that line of code worked perfectly.  Thanks so much!